# Multiple regex lookbehind

Tags: regex, positive-lookbehind

I am searching for a string which has several occurrences of other string/char before it:

this is not real example, but it describes what I want to capture - **string that occurs right after second (or third, the expression must be scalable and configurable) occurrence of the ":" character.**

```
boo+foo:qoo+loo:thisIsWhatIneed...
```

Obviously, the following did not work:

```
(?<=\:){2,}.*
```

and this would be pretty much opposite (inverted) of what I want:

```
.*:.*:
```

[image]

Comment: Most regexp engines require lookbehinds to be fixed-length. Can you use a capture group for the part you need instead of a lookbehind?

Comment: `.*` should be `[^:]*` or `.*?` so it doesn't match `:` characters.

Comment: Does `(?:.*?:){2}(.*)` work for what you need? That gives "thisIsWhatIneed..." as group 1. Similarly, `(?:.*?:){1}(.*)` gives group 1 as "qoo+loo:thisIsWhatIneed...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will match what you needed from your example:

`[^:]*:[^:]*:(.*)`

ignored:ignored:captured as group 1

This will let you specify the number of colon delimited words to ignore more easily:

`(?:[^:]*:){2}(.*)`

This will capture everything after the last colon until the end, regardless of how many colons there are:

`:([^:]*)$`

[image: regex test website showing results]

Comment: Your examples are great, however I work in special crippled tool based on Java, which works only with full matches and not with groups. Any idea how could I convert group 1 to match?

Comment: How about using the last pattern? Or maybe even `[^:]*$`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture something after some fixed number of `:` then somthing along these lines is your best bet:

```
/^(?:[^:]+:){2}([^:]*)/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iANYd8/1)

If you want something after ALL colons, like the last field of some line delimited by `:` than you can do:

```
/([^:]*$)/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1Wou0I/1)

In both cases you are essentially 'counting colons' from the front or the back of the string; if from the front, use `^` and `$` from the back.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of lookbehinds, why not a lookahead?

```
(?<=\:)        # Match something follows a ':'
(?!            # that is not
  \w+\+\w+     # two "words" separated by a '+'
  (?::|$)      # followed by either another ':' or the end of string.
)              # 
.*             #
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Mmbg4J/1).

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I want to capture - **string that occurs right after second ... occurrence of the ":" character.** ...*

A capture group would be a logical approach here.

```
:.+:(.+)
```

Attempting to match only the text, utilizing a *positive look-behind*, typically requires a fixed-length.
Although, some *regex engine*'s allow for variable-length *look-behind*'s—i.e., *JavaScript* and *.NET*.

If you're using either of those, you can use the following pattern.

```
(?<=:.*:).+
```

```js
var s = 'boo+foo:qoo+loo:thisIsWhatIneed...'
console.log(s.match(/(?<=:.*:).+/))
```